# How to run WCF service while changing the namespace in WCF Service Application project?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-4

I have added "**WCF Service Application**" project type to my VS solution(4.0). Now, the default namespace that appears is "**Service**" and if I run the application (Pointing WCF service application as the startup project) it works fine.

Now I have changed the namespace to **XXX.YYY.Service.PartnerPortal** as under

```
namespace XXX.YYY.Service.PartnerPortal
{        
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }        
    }
}
```

As well as the IService1 interface also

```
namespace XXX.YYY.Service.PartnerPortal
{    
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);        
    }
}
```

*Also I have changed the default namespace in the project properties*

The app.config file is as under

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>  

    <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And while trying to run, the error messageI am receiving is

Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:65192/Service1.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange Error    URI: http://localhost:65192/Service1.svc    Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:65192/Service1.svc'.    The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.HTTP GET Error    URI: http://localhost:65192/Service1.svc    There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:65192/Service1.svc'.    The request failed with the error message:--            The type 'Service.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.                 body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}          p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }         pre {font-family:"Lucida Console";font-size: .9em}         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}         .version {color: gray;}         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }

## Server Error in '/' Application.

### *The type 'Service.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.*

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.            
             **Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'Service.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.
            **Source Error:** 
                                                                   `An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.`                                                         
            **Stack Trace:** 
                                                                   `[InvalidOperationException: The type 'Service.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.]   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +51530   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1461   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +44   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +651[ServiceActivationException: The service '/Service1.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The type 'Service.Service1', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found..]   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +688590   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +190   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService) +234   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +359   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75`                                                         
                        **Version Information:**ÿMicrosoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272                --.

What wrong I am doing and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open your svc file, and correct the namespace in the Service attribute value

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XXX.YYY.Service.PartnerPortal.Service1" .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed the configuration file as under

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="Service.Service1Behavior" name="XXX.YYY.Service.PartnerPortal.Service1">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="XXX.YYY.Service.PartnerPortal.IService1">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost"/>
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="Service.Service1Behavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```